# Kohana ORM & SQL Injection

Tags: kohana-3

What's the best way to prevent SQL Injection in Kohana(3.3) using native ORM? 
Or it's "safe" by default..

Answer (score 6):

It is safe by default as it uses [Kohana's Database Query Builder](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/database/query/builder) which does all the necessary escaping for you. **Kohana's ORM is safe.**

Comment: No it's not. Don't be fooled by fancy builders. Look closer on limit or offset methods in ORM and not only them...